# Ordering negatives with should (or shouldn't) + verb

Tags: negation

There was some debate at work the other day as to the correct form in the following case:

1) I don't think you should do that.

or

2) I think you shouldn't do that.

A few of us set off on a Google spiral that threw up a few hits but with nothing - as far as I can tell - with a definitive answer. There were a few threads here, but none that were dealing specifically with this issue.

A few also came up at wordreference, but there was nothing definitive, and some contradictory answers seemed to surface. From the research we found the following:

1) Americans say either, but the British always prefer to put the negative first (as in: I don't think you should).
2) There is a slight variance in meaning (at least denotational if not literally grammatical) when one places the negative first.

There were many other things said, but no research was provided.

So I am asking here if anyone has a definitive answer, or is this simply a stylistic choice possibly conditioned by whatever side of the Atlantic you happened to grow up?

Apologies for the rambling post.

Much appreciated.

Comment: You are correct, but I'm not in a position to provide references. The British phrase things less definitively, in general: "I don't think you should do that" is more tentative in phrasing than "I think you shouldn't do that", even though the Brit is attempting to convey "that is a bad idea" just the same as the American is.

Comment: Here's a reference: http://www.glottopedia.org/index.php/Negative_raising

Answer (score 1):

By and large, people use these interchangeably. I used to be a stickler for using the correct version, but no one generally cares about the distinction and I've given up on (some of) my teenage rebel pedantry.

---

Pedantically, there is a distinction:

> 1) I don't think you should do that.

No thought (that you should do that) has occurred to me. **I lack an opinion** on the subject, either because I never considered it or I never made up my mind about it.

I am **certain** that I haven't thought about this.

> 2) I think you shouldn't do that.

I have thought to myself that you shouldn't do that. **I have an opinion**, i.e. a disapproving one.

I am **uncertain** whether my opinion is objectively correct.

Compare this to:

> 3) You shouldn't do that.

I am **certain** that this is objectively correct.

---

The reason it's so hard for us is because of *"I don't think"*. It is *very* loosely used; and can be interpreted to either mean:

- "My mind is made up. I disagree."
- "I have not made up my mind about it."

*Literally*, only the latter is correct. But people have started using it for the former too.

This lack of distinction is causing the issue. If we avoid using "I don't know", it becomes much easier to see that these are not equivalent statements.

> 1) I'm not going to paint the house you bought.
>   2) I'm going to paint the house you didn't buy.
>
> 1) I shouted that OJ Simpson didn't do it.
>   2) I didn't shout that OJ Simpson did it.
>
> 1) I appreciate that you don't steal from me.
>   2) I don't appreciate that you steal from me.

You can't just shift the negation from one side to the other, it dramatically changes the meaning.

---

**Why I think this is the case.**

Euphemistic language and politeness.

"I think you shouldn't do that" is considered more confrontational that "I don't think you should do that".

The former is a blunt statement that you *disagree* with them. The latter, comparatively speaking, adds a softer implication of *doubt* rather than *certain disagreement*.

Consider a different example:

> 1) Please move your car.
>   2) Can you move your car please?

Both are a request. Both use "please". But the second sentence is still considered more polite, because it implicitly includes the option that the person is *willing but unable* to move their car. To translate:

> 1) Move your car
>   2) Move your car **if possible**.

Applying the same principle to your original example:

> 1) *I don't think that [assertion].*
>   I ***cannot confirm*** your assertion.
>
> 2) *I think [negated assertion].*
>   I **disagree** that your assertion is correct.

(1) allows for the option that you can't definitively answer whether or not it should be done. (2), however, is relatively certain about disagreeing with the initial stance.

Since (2) comes on stronger than (1), (1) is the more polite option and therefore valid to use if you want to be seen as a courteous human being.